# I'm using Qwik and I have this error on some pages

Tags: javascript, qwik

I'm using Qwik and i have this error on some pages

```
    Failed to resolve module specifier "X". Relative references must start with either 
    "/", "./", or "../".
```

but when i wrap this page content in component error is gone.

```
   const index=()=>{
   return <Component/>
}
```